# Image Comparision using openCV and JavaCV stucked at last step - what next step

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing, javacv, image-compression

Following is a small code I wrote using the existing examples, it’s to compare 2 images. Requirement is to check whether the small image is a part of the large image.

```
    String smallUrl = "rsz_our-mobile-planet-us-infographic_infographics_lg_unberela.jpg";
    String largeUrl = "our-mobile-planet-us-infographic_infographics_lg.jpg";

    IplImage image = cvLoadImage(largeUrl,CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED );
    IplImage image2 = cvLoadImage(smallUrl,CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED ); 

    CvMat descriptorsA = new CvMat(null);
    CvMat descriptorsB = new CvMat(null);

    final FastFeatureDetector ffd = new FastFeatureDetector(40, true);
    final KeyPoint keyPoints = new KeyPoint();
    final KeyPoint keyPoints2 = new KeyPoint();

    ffd.detect(image, keyPoints, null);
    ffd.detect(image2, keyPoints2, null);

    System.out.println("keyPoints.size() : "+keyPoints.size());
    System.out.println("keyPoints2.size() : "+keyPoints2.size());
     // BRISK extractor = new  BRISK();
     //BriefDescriptorExtractor extractor = new BriefDescriptorExtractor();
    FREAK extractor = new FREAK();

    extractor.compute(image, keyPoints, descriptorsA);
    extractor.compute(image2, keyPoints2, descriptorsB);

    System.out.println("descriptorsA.size() : "+descriptorsA.size());
    System.out.println("descriptorsB.size() : "+descriptorsB.size());

    DMatch dmatch = new DMatch();
    //FlannBasedMatcher matcher = new FlannBasedMatcher();
    //DescriptorMatcher matcher = new DescriptorMatcher();

    BFMatcher matcher = new BFMatcher();
    matcher.match(descriptorsA, descriptorsB, dmatch, null);

    System.out.println(dmatch.capacity());
```

Now after calling the match() method I need to make a decision whether the small image is a part of large image, probably with some threshold values like 90% match etc.

I am stucked at this point and honestly I have no idea to proceed with this. I can guess there is something to do with the dmatch object and I also found there are other methods like knnMatch and radiusMatch. But still I couldn’t find any proper guide for this.

It would be a great help if someone can guide me at this point.

Comment: take a look at this tutorial: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_homography/feature_homography.html. (It's using C++ interface, but I am sure you can figure it out its Java version). Essentially, after finding all the matches, you need to do a geometry verification step.

Comment: Thanks , will have a look and come back.

Comment: Any more suggestions, still not success with this :-(

Comment: Still waiting for options